# Javascript URL redirection if webpage URL link fails

Tags: javascript, html

I have recently taken responsibility for a website belonging to a good friend.
On one page he has embedded, a rtsp video webcam stream which is received from a Wowza media server (a simple URL address). This works very well indeed.

However occasionally because of local network problems at the webcam location, the stream will fail with a simple black display saying 'media-not-found'.

He has asked me that during these periods of 'media-not-found', could the whole page redirect to another URL?

I've struggled to find a simple solution, so any ideas would be appreciated.
The website pages are currently written in a mix of html and javascript.

Comment: Can we have some code for the error ?

Answer (score 1):

you just have to do

```
if (err) {
  window.location = 'http://newurl.com'
}
```

Comment: This is the embedded container, for which if it fails ... I need the redirect to another URL.

Comment: <!-- player container -->
<!--  <center> <p>The Webcam</p> -->
<div id="player-container"><p>This Feed Uses Adobe Flash Player</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
embedPlayer('player-container', {
    flashvars : {
       'rtmp' : 'rtmp://xxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxx:xxxx/live/camera.stream',         //rtmp or rtmpt link to Casanet live broadcast alias; not set by default;  the player automatically reconnects using RTMPT if RTMP connection fails
       
    playerStyle : 'quick'
});
</script>
<!-- end of player container -->